# Loading Application Settings in an azure webapp for a .NET Core 2.0 WebAPI

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-webjobs

I have a .NET Core 2 WebAPI project which is hosted in azure. I'm trying to load in ApplicationSettings stored in the azure portal so that I can hold the details to my repositories securely.

My code to retrieve the AppSetting looks like this:

```
private DocumentClient CreateDocumentClient()
{
    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseEndpoint"];
    var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseKey"];
    return new DocumentClient(new Uri(url), key);
}
```

My understanding is that I need to add Environment Variables to the config, however I think this has changed in the later version of .NET core and all the various tutorials and guides are sending me around in circles.

I believe I need to add this to the Program.cs in V2.0 rather than the Startup so I've tried changing from this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

To this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((WebHostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder) =>
         {
             builder.Sources.Clear();
             builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
         })
         .UseStartup<Startup>()
         .Build();
```

But this doesn't seem to work either (the values are still null). I should add that I don't have an appsettings.json file and so haven't included it as many other examples have shown.

Am I in the right place? How can I load the ApplicationSettings from azure into my application?

Comment: Did you see this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/06/12/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service/)?

Comment: @DavidEbbo I've solved this, based on your comment - do you want to answer to get the rep? Only seems fair!

Comment: answer needs to be more than the link, and I didn't have time to write it up. Feel free you write and accept your own answer.

Comment: @DavidEbbo no that's fine - I just didn't want to take your link, write an answer, and steal a credit. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - really appreciate it!